# Making a scrollTo anchor function inside an ng-view without changing url

Tags: html, angularjs, single-page-application

So I'm making a SPA with some different views in it. One of my views has to load about 9000 categories from my DB. I've tried do use the normal anchor notaion,

```
 <a href="#a#>A</a>
```

but this changes my url and forces the site to make another call to my db which is deffently not wanted.
I know this might seem like a duplicate question but havent found any answers that I could use for my problem yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at this [directive](https://github.com/RallySoftware/angular-bootstrap-affix), I think it does the trick for you.